# Rails3.1 - How do I include css files in some views but not others?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, compass-sass

It seems that, in rails 3.1, all of the css.scss files get merged into 1 file.  What do I do if I want a css file to only be included in some views?  Like if I want admin.css.scss included in the admin page and main.css.scss in the home/about/contact page.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Rails 3.1, all your stylesheets will be merged into the application.css if your application.css looks like:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll automatically include all the stylesheets available in this directory
 * and any sub-directories. You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at
 * the top of the compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree . 
*/
```

It's due to the *=require_tree .

You can require a specific stylesheet with:

```
*= require main
```

Otherwise, in your layout, you write:

```
%head
 = yield :head
```

and in your page:

```
= content_for :head do
 = stylesheet_link_tag 'stylesheet'
```

Comment: What does the %head and yield :head bits do?

Comment: In Haml:

%head
 = yield :head

Will generate the <head> tag in HTML and insert the code from another page via the yield

Answer (score 10):

Let me add a solution that worked for me.

As mentioned in a previous answer you might want to remove the

```
 *= require_tree .
```

statement from the **application.css** file.

I kept the

```
 *= require_self
```

statement for shared styles across the application.

Then in my **application.html** file I used the following statements to include only the **application.css** and the **controller.controller_name.css** style sheets in the view.

```
= stylesheet_link_tag "application", controller.controller_name
= javascript_include_tag "application", controller.controller_name
```

As you can see the same works for JavaScript files.

Answer (score 3):

See also:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

(see sections 2.2.14    'Finding Layouts')

you could have different layouts for different controllers!

e.g. under app/views/layouts you could have application.haml and admin.haml
and under app/controllers you'd have a admin_controller.rb

Rails will try to find a layout with the same name as the controller.

You can also override this behavior and specify which layout to use, e.g.:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  layout "admin"
  #...
end
```

You would then create an admin.scss file under  app/stylesheets  for this new layout!

Comment: +1 for actually specifying which section to look at, instead of dumping the same old link.

Comment: thanks. yes, it's a loooong page, and they changed the section numbers